# How to autogenerate phpDOC for classes/function on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpdoc

Any idea how to generate phpdoc on VSCode? I have installed intellisense, intelephense extensions but when I type `/**` it just adds `*/` so it becomes something like
`/** */` and that's all. No autogenerated PHP doc, nothing no matter this is done above the class definition or a regular function.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DEVSENSE.phptools-vscode generates doc comments (details at https://docs.devsense.com/en/vscode/editor/phpdoc)

Answer (score 2):

with a VSCode extension you can do it, but not with the same shortcut (`"/**" + ENTER`)

I found 3 :

- **PHPDoc Comment**

[VSCode Marketplace for PHPDoc Comment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rexshi.phpdoc-comment-vscode-plugin)

Shortcut : `CMD + SHIFT + I`

- **PHPDoc Generator**

[VSCode Marketplace for PHPDoc Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ronvanderheijden.phpdoc-generator)

Shortcut : `CTRL + ENTER`

- **PHPDoc Generator 2022**

[VSCode Marketplace for PHPDoc Generator 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SamuelHinchliffe.phpdoc-generator-2022)

Shortcut : `CTRL + ENTER`

I don't find another way do to this like PHPStorm

---

I tried the first one :

```
function getNameFromNumber($num) {
    $numeric = $num % 26;
    $letter = chr(65 + $numeric);
    $num2 = intval($num / 26);
    if ($num2 > 0) {
        return $this->getNameFromNumber($num2 - 1) . $letter;
    } else {
        return $letter;
    }
}
```

With a right click I can :

[image]

```
/**
 * getNameFromNumber
 *
 * @param  mixed $num
 * @return void
 */
function getNameFromNumber($num) {
    $numeric = $num % 26;
    $letter = chr(65 + $numeric);
    $num2 = intval($num / 26);
    if ($num2 > 0) {
        return $this->getNameFromNumber($num2 - 1) . $letter;
    } else {
        return $letter;
    }
}
```

I work like a charm ;)

---

Hope it can help you

Bye

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DEVSENSE.phptools-vscode which does it in all ways (and soon to be generating AI summary as well)

docs: https://docs.devsense.com/en/vscode/editor/phpdoc

Answer (score 1):

As of 2024, the most popular VSCode extension for this seems to be [PHP DocBlocker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=neilbrayfield.php-docblocker).

Create a new blank line above your function/method/class/var and type `/` `*` `*` (`Enter` or `Tab`).

You can then type your comments and `Tab` through each "field" in the doc block, eg. type "My function name" then hit `Tab` to highlight the next field, eg. `@param` where you can type "string $str The string to pass to my function", then `Tab` to the `@return` portion, etc., etc.